# Absolute Value of Uniform

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, conditional-probability

I want to check if my reasoning here is correct: Given $X \sim U([-1,1])$ and $Y=|X|$, then it holds that $Y \sim U([0,1])$. Now if we let $(X,Y),(X',Y')$ be two i.i.d. draws, such that $Y=|X|$ and $Y'=|X'|$, then is the following true:
$$
P(Y\le Y'|X=x,X'=x') = P(Y\le Y')=1/2
$$
for any $x,x' \in [-1,1]?$

Comment: The answers point out that the given probability is either 0 or 1 because the random selection is outside of the probability, but I suspect that's not what you're looking for. Did you perhaps mean to make the random selection part of the probability, like so: $P(\left | X_{1} \right | \leq \left | X_{2} \right | \mid X_{1} \sim U([-1,1]), X_{2} \sim U([-1,1]))$

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, because given $X,X'$, you have the values for $Y,Y'$. So, the probability is either $1$ or $0$, depending on $x,x'$:
$$P(Y\leq Y'|X=x,X'=x')=\mathbb I(|x|\leq |x'|)$$

Comment: are there any simple examples of X,Y for which equality would hold here ?

Comment: @WeakLearner X & Y are already well defined in the question statement, what do you mean by examples?

Comment: @gunes as I am trying to come up with an example of random variables X,Y such that P(Y < Y'|X,X') = P(Y<Y') for (X,Y), (X',Y') drawn independently -  so a different data generating process altogether

Comment: If X and X’ are completely independent of Y and Y’, that would always hold.

Comment: @gunes yes sorry, i should have been more clear - I want to find a distribution of X,Y, say P, such that X and Y are not independent and for two randomly sampled draws from P, the equality holds

Comment: @WeakLearner: Best to ask this as an entirely new question, rather than trying to shoe-horn it into the comment thread.

Comment: @Ben Ok, I've done that here: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/515343/55946

Comment: @JamesMartin may you please help in this (already linked) question? [Conditioning on probability zero: Can we say $P(B \le A|B=b) = P(b \le A|B=b)$?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/515364/conditioning-on-probability-zero-can-we-say-pb-le-ab-b-pb-le-ab-b)

Answer (score 6):

No, that is false.  Once you condition on $X$ and $X'$ the event $Y \leqslant Y'$ is deterministic.  Specifically, you have:

$$\mathbb{P}(Y \leqslant Y'|X=x, X'=x') = \mathbb{I}(|x| \leqslant |x'|).$$