# Examples for which conditional probability is equal to uncondtional probability

Tags: probability, conditional-probability

I am looking for an example where $(X_1,Y_1), (X_2, Y_2)$ are two random samples from some distribution $D$, and for which $X,Y$ are not independent, and $P(Y_1 \le Y_2|X_1,X_2) = P(Y_1 \le Y_2)$. See my related question [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/515333/55946)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Choose any two different continuous distributions $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ such that if $W_1\sim\mu_1$ and $W_2\sim\mu_2$ independently, then $P(W_1\leq W_2)=1/2$. (For example, this always holds if both $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ are symmetric around the same point, e.g. $\mu_1=U[-a_1,a_1]$ and $\mu_2=U[-a_2,a_2]$ for any $a_1,a_2>0$.)

Now define the distribution of your $(X,Y)$ as follows. Let $X$ take values $1$ and $2$ with probability $1/2$ each. Then conditional on $X=x$, let $Y$ have distribution $\mu_x$.

This distribution has the property that you are looking for. $X$ and $Y$ are not independent since $\mu_1\ne\mu_2$. Conditioned on the values of $X_1, X_2$, either both $Y_1, Y_2$ have distribution $\mu_1$, or both have distribution $\mu_2$, or one has distribution $\mu_1$ and the other has distribution $\mu_2$. In all cases the conditional probability that $Y_1\leq Y_2$ is $1/2$.

Comment: Obviously $P(W_1 \leq W_2)＝1/2$ cannot be true for "any" two different continuous distributions. For example, $W_1 \sim N(0, 1), W_2 \sim N(0, 2)$.

Comment: @Zhanxiong I don't understand what you mean. I am saying, take any two distributions such that $P(W_1\leq W_2)=1/2$ holds. I give an example where it holds. And indeed it does hold in your example with $W_1\sim N(0,1)$ and $W_2\sim N(0,2)$. Obviously it does not hold for all distributions!

Comment: Apology, I made some calculation error I guess.